# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'self'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, attributeerror

I have a gui file and I designed it with qtdesigner, and there are another py file. I tried to changing button name or tried to add item in listwidget but I didn't make that things. I got an error message.

My codes;

```
from gui import Ui_mainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import main


class Music(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.searchbutton)

    def searchbutton(self):
        base = main.Main()
        self.url = base.search(self.search_box.text())
        self.dict = base.get_data(self.url)
        print(self.dict)
        for i in self.dict:
        self.setupUi.self.listWidget.addItem(i)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = Music()
gui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and gui.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(413, 613)
        mainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(413, 613))
        mainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(413, 613))
        mainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.musics_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.musics_frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 49, 411, 441))
        self.musics_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.musics_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.musics_frame)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 391, 421))
        self.listWidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(5, 5))
        self.listWidget.setGridSize(QtCore.QSize(5, 5))
        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        #  ....
        #  ....
        #  ....
```

and my error message

```
  File "/home/yavuz/Genel/youtube-sounds/music.py", line 19, in searchbutton
    self.setupUi.self.listWidget.addItem(i)
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'self'
```

Comment: `self.setupUi` is a method and doesn't have a `self`. I'm not a Qt person so can't say wha you are supposed to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ui class as a mixin, all the widgets from Qt Designer will be added as instance attributes of the `Music` class. So you just want:

```
    self.listWidget.addItem(i)
```

PS: and set the icon/grid size to something sensible (e.g. `32 x 32`), otherwise the list items will be too small to see.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this time items didn't add in qlistwidget. And there is no error.

Comment: @yunver. That must be because there's nothing in `self.dict`.

Comment: no, there are names and links in self.dict. I run my app and I wrote a special name in Qlineedit and than I clicked search button, than self.dict has names and links, but didn't add it in Qlistwidget. @ekhumoro

Comment: an anather example, I created anorher dict for example dictionary = {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3} and I use it but It didn't add QlistWidget again. There is no errors.

Comment: @yunver. Please check your code more carefully: see my updated answer.